# Launching a grails-app through Intelli-J with root set to localhost:8080/ instead of localhost:8080/app, or modifying createLink?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, url-mapping

Is there a way to launch an application through Intelli-J so that it makes `localhost:8080/` the root of the application? The problem I'm having is that AJAX urls that work locally don't work in production, and `createLink(action:"ajaxUpdate")` seems to create references to `/app/ajaxUpdate`, which works locally but not in production.

Is there a way to fix `createLink` to work in both locations? I thought perhaps I could just use UrlMappings to make all the ajax calls pretty and just refer to `/ajaxUpdate`, but that doesn't work because of how the grails application is deployed within Intelli-J.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About your problem, in **grails-app/conf/Config.groovy** you can specify the server URL, like this:

```
environments {
    production {

        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost/"  // Specify the "root" of your link
        ....
    }

    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then the createLink method should be fine. As I know, it's about Grails config, not relate to IntelliJ.

EDIT: It seems that I missed some information: to make the createLink start at "http://localhost/", it's necessary to add another line into Config.groovy:

```
grails.app.context = "/"
```

Comment: I should have checked this first. I bet I even configured this for production v_v.

Comment: @Stefan: I had the same problem before. Hope this help

Comment: This isn't working. 'createLink' still generates /app/main/whatever, when it needs to generate /main/whatever.

Comment: @Stefan: how did you change it? Have you tried "grails clean"?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have one Url Mapping: " `"/"(controller:"main")`. Even if I specify grails.serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/" in the development/test environment, the application is still available on :8080/app, rather than :8080. Because of this, urls that work in development don't work in production.

Comment: @Stefan: it seems I missed some details: add this to your Config.groovy: grails.app.context = "/" . I have tested it out in Development,it's ok.

Comment: That's what I was missing. You might also be interested in answering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999846/grails-run-app-on-localhost8080-instead-of-8080-appname   :P

Comment: @Stefan: thanks, but looks like I'm a little late. That's a perfect question & answer.