# grails run-app on localhost:8080 instead of :8080/appName?

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy

Is there a way to get grails run-app to launch on `localhost:8080/` instead of `localhost:8080/${appName}`?

In `Config.groovy,`, setting `grails.serverUrl` has absolutely no effect - it only seems to affect absolute url generation of different grails methods.

In production, I use apache virtualhosts to mask `site.com:8080/appName` as `site.com`. I want to make my test configuration match production.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about

```
grails.app.context = "/"
```

in `Config.groovy`, as per [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-2534?focusedCommentId=136656&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_136656) jira discussion?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Grails 3.1.1 you can add the following line to your
`grails-app/conf/application.yml` file to bring back the `http://localhost:8080/appName` functionality:

```
server:
    'contextPath': '/appName'
```

Replace `appName` with your application's actual name (i.e. the folder name that the `grails-app` folder is in).

Answer (score 0):

With recent versions of Grails this can also be set in *application.properties*:

app.context=/