# Grails get war baseUrl intelligently?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, groovy, war

My baseUrl is `http://localhost:8080/whatever`. On other machines, it's `http://localhost/whatever`.

Is there a smart way to get this information without using

```
<%
    String baseUrl = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath()
%>
```

I'm trying to dynamically create some links to path parameterized rest URLS, i.e:

`http://localhost:8080/a/b/${param1}/c/${param2}`

If there's a better way to do this, let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you forget, isn't that was answered in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989528/launching-a-grails-app-through-intelli-j-with-root-set-to-localhost8080-instead/4989644#4989644). Just set the `grails.serverURL` and `grails.app.context` in the configuration file of your deployed machine. Then use `createLink` to make the URL. Or I missed something?

Comment: You missed nothing. I knew that this path had to exist in some configuration SOMEWHERE. I completely missed this in Config.groovy

Answer (score 7):

This solution doesn't require grails.serverURL to be set:

`<g:createLink absolute='true' uri='/WHATEVER'/>` or

`${g.createLink(absolute:true, uri:"/WHATEVER")}`

will generate:

`http://HOST:PORT/APPNAME/WHATEVER`

Set the `URI` to point to where you want to in the app. Use `'/'` for the base URL of your app:

`http://HOST:PORT/APPNAME/`

Answer (score 0):

the [<g:link>](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/link.html) tag accepts a parameter, "absolute=true", that will build a URL that respects the current environment's serverUrl and contextPath. I recommend combining that with a [named URL mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4.9%20Named%20URL%20Mappings) to build your URL.

If you're unable to build your entire URL at page rendering time, Grails can still build part of the URL for you:

```
var url = '${g.createLink(absolute: true, mapping: "mymappingname")}/' + param1 + '/c/' + param2;
console.log(url); // "http://localhost:8080/whatever/a/b/something/c/somethingelse"
```

And in UrlMappings.groovy:

```
class UrlMappings {

name mymappingname: "/a/b/$param1?/c/$param2?" {
        controller = 'myRestHandler'
    }
}
```

Comment: The links are parameterized with javascript, so this approach won't work.

Comment: <script>var url = '${g.createLink(absolute: true, url: '/')}/'</script> Then you can use url as the base for your javascript urls.

Comment: This still won't work. /c/ is actually multiple different dynamic mappings, and the base Url for "/" is mapped to the file I need the baseUrl in, so naming that mapping does no good.

Answer (score 0):

I solve using createLink(action: 'index', controller: 'Root', params: [id: id], absolute: true)